# svgwrite example code not showing anything

Tags: python, svgwrite

I installed the svgwrite package, and ran the example code at the very first of the README

```
dwg = svgwrite.Drawing('test.svg', profile='tiny')
dwg.add(dwg.line((0, 0), (10, 0), stroke=svgwrite.rgb(10, 10, 16, '%')))
dwg.add(dwg.text('Test', insert=(0, 0.2), fill='red'))
dwg.save()
```

However when I generate the image, I don't see anything in my SVG preview.
[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

By default the generated XML is not pretty-printed.
It looks like it's just flowing off-screen in your preview.